# I think I've created a new type of puzzle: "Word ___"

Tags: word, wordplay, anagram

I think I've created a new type of puzzle. I call it "Word ___"

Here is how to solve it:
The word in the above blank is the answer for this puzzle.
Step 1: Make a copy of the equations, but replacing words with synonyms.
Step 2: Add/Remove letters to blank as per the +/- signs in the equation.
Step 3: Find an annagram of the letter jumble created in step2 that creates a word.

Ex: Weep + Hole + Jewelery - Hurts = ____ →
Cry + Pit + Charms - Harms = Cryptic

Now for the real thing:

Same + Proportion + Close - Taste + Me - Track = ___

Hint 1:

> Taste is as in "an ear for music"

Hint 2:

> Track has to do with trains, but isn't "Train"

Hint 3:

> A synonym for the answer is Comparison

Comment: Just a thought - this puzzle is *really hard* for anyone to solve. The only possible confirmation of correctness/progress is *if* you manage to guess the meaning each word is meant in and then *if* you manage to find the correct synonym for each word and then *if* you manage to anagram them correctly, there is an English word at the end of it all - a word that isn't even clued, giving even less confirmation. (Well I guess the fact that it has to fit in the blank is *some* confirmation, but lots and lots of words would work there as a title)

Comment: I put in an edit clarifying your post. I think its an interesting type of puzzle.

Comment: @Ankit going to copy my edit rejection reason - Please DO NOT clarify questions without confirmation from the poster. In addition, adding code formatting damages accessibility.

Comment: Indirect anagrams have long been deprecated in cryptic crossword clues because they are practically impossible to work out. By this is meant a clue where you solve a simple definition-type clue to get the letters which you must then anagram. Your puzzle involves an indirect anagram where you'd need to solve 4 definition clues correctly to get the right anagram fodder. At least with a crossword clue you know the answer's length. In your puzzle you don't even give that.  It is practically impossible to work out, for just this reason.

Comment: Not entirely sure how adding *two* more indirect anagrams will make the puzzle any easier...

Comment: Not only that, @bobble: The recent addition of two more terms to the, erm, comparison makes me wonder whether the puzzle was solvable in its original form. This looks a bit like a patch to fix the puzzle in retrospect. Otherwise, the two new terms would have to be anagrams of each other, no?

Comment: (Okay, sorry, I have just seen the comments on the answer below.)

Comment: Although this puzzle was poor in its presented form (due to the noted errors and clumsy fix-up), those who are saying it's too hard are clearly wrong given that the puzzle was in effect solved despite the errors (which were only found when the correct solution couldn't be made to fit!). Independent clues to the final word allow the equation to be re-arranged to see if any of the ambiguous clues give something intelligible for an "impossible" clue... but only if the puzzle setter takes care to provide a correct (and sufficiently short) equation in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

The name of the new type of puzzle you created is:

> "Word Equation"!

Equation in OP for reference:

> Same + Proportion + Close - Taste + Me - Track = ___

- Same:

> Equal

- Proportion

> Ratio

- Close

> Near

- Taste

> Ear -- tough one! We arrive at this one more by process of elimination (to make the word equation work), and with the aid of Hint #1: Taste is as in "an ear for music".

- Me

> I -- this part of the puzzle was added later to fix an issue.

- Track

> Rail -- this part of the puzzle was added later to fix an issue. There was a set of leftover letters 'RLA', which '+I-RAIL' gets rid of.

Put it all together:

> EQUAL + RATIO + NEAR - EAR + I - RAIL
>  = (EQUA)L + RA(TIO) + (N)EAR - EAR + I - RAIL
>  = EQUATION + L + RA + EAR - EAR + I - RAIL
>  = EQUATION

--

Leaving my initial post for better context on the comments below the solution:

*[Posted 2021-08-24 06:31:07Z]*

Not a full solution, just some ideas.

I feel very good about:

> * Same: equal
>  * Proportion: ratio / fraction
>  * Close: near / shut / ???
>  * Taste: flavor / savor / sample
>
>  Yielding 'Equation' (Word Equation)
>
>
>  But struggling to make it all connect.
>
>  At first I thought it may be Word Alliteration, but struggled to easily add a 2nd 'L'.

Comment: Equation is correct. You also got Same = Equal, one of your Proportion and clear guesses were correct, and I added a hint for Taste.

Comment: @Boesf that still leaves us with `l` from equal and `ra` from ratio unsubtracted, isn't it?

Comment: @Boesf Oh cool! Just so I understand, rot13(1. Gur flabalz bs 'pybfr' zhfg unir na 'a' va vg gb svavfu 'rdhngvba', 2. naq gur flabalz bs 'gnfgr' zhfg ng yrnfg unir 'y', 'e' 'n' naq 'a' va vg gb fhogenpg gur zvavzhz yrsgbire yrggref bs 'rdhny', 'engvb'/'senpgvba' naq gur flabalz bs 'pybfr' jvgu na 'a', pbeerpg? V gevrq gb svaq jbeqf gung fngvfsl guvf ohg frrz gb or fgehttyvat rira jvgu gur uvag lbh cbfgrq unun)

Comment: @Boesf according to your comment equal + ratio/fraction + near/shut - ______ = equation, correct?

Comment: @Ankit Correct.

Comment: @Boesf I tried all four possible options... I then plugged in the remaining letters into an anagram solver and forget synonyms of close, I didn't even get words! Are you sure there isn't a mistake in the problem?

Comment: [!!! SPOILERS !!!] [!!! SPOILERS !!!] [!!! SPOILERS !!!] I thought @Boesf confirmed NEAR: EQUAL, PROPORTION: RATIO|FRACTION, solution: EQUATION. But we have no info on CLOSE or TASTE, except for the hint on TASTE: >Taste is as in "an ear for music" --- Nevertheless, EQUATION minus EQUAL+RATIO|FRACTION leaves LRA|LRAFC, with LRA being common to both, so we know the synonym of TASTE needs to contain LRA. I tried several anagram solvers and thesaurus.com but didn't really make progress :D

Comment: @justhalf Fixed.

Comment: @SpiritFryer Lra was a mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: @Boesf: It seems that your new addition is just there to get rid of the excess LRA (RAIL − I). If so, the signs in the new equation are wrong: You'll need −(TRACK − ME) = −TRACK + ME, which makes  everything needlessly complicated.

Comment: @MOehm Fixed it.

Comment: Anyway, it is clear now what the solution is. The overall answer was found pretty early on (and the presentation of the puzzle confirms it, which is nice). But I don't think the puzzle in its form can be salvaged. Indirect anagrams are hard; "close" is a word with many meanings and with even more synonyms; "ear" for taste is rather loose. You had a creative idea there, but it didn't work out, I'm afraid.

Comment: (But perhaps my criticism of using anagrams is a bit too harsh. It seems that in the originally intentded puzzle, the letters of the answer all appear in the same order as in the summands; only the letters to be subtracted must be anagrammed. Some of that ambiguity may have been introduced by Ankit's edit.)

Comment: @Boesf Aw, happens. Edited and completed my solution to reflect the changes!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> Equation, as found by SpiritFryer

Because:

> Equal + ratio + near - ear + i - rail = equa**lra**tion**eari** (with bold being letters both in a + and - word) leaving equation.